# d: library 'GoogleToolboxForMac' not found clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

**When I try to take build in Xcode the below error is showing**

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lGoogleToolboxForMac', '-lc++'
ld: warning: search path '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/waWha-fulbgiaojoeqcuezkrdtdfvoaoet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/waWha-fulbgiaojoeqcuezkrdtdfvoaoet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/waWha-fulbgiaojoeqcuezkrdtdfvoaoet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/waWha-fulbgiaojoeqcuezkrdtdfvoaoet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf' not found
ld: warning: search path '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/waWha-fulbgiaojoeqcuezkrdtdfvoaoet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb' not found
ld: library 'GoogleToolboxForMac' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I have updated the pod but still the error is not cleared. The GoogleToolboxForMac is linked in the link binary with libraries under the build phase. Need any solutions immediately.**